# Bootstrap discounted cash flow

Tags: discount-factor-curve

I'm trying to follow the case study here and wasn't able to get the same discounted cash flow table as is shown in step 3 under Part II. 
[bootstrap discounted cash flow](https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/2012/09/practice-test-exam-question-and-solution-bootstrapping-zero-and-forward-curves-case-study/)

[image]

Below is the cash flow table I got. 
[image]
Can someone please explain why in that example it'd assume same amount of discounted cash flow from column 6-10? I'm able to match with the example under Part I. So i want to make sure I didn't overlook anything when it comes to multi-period payment cycle (semi-annual in this case).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see your screenshot. But I think you should just follow some real examples online instead of having people find out what's wrong on your side.

This is an excel example, go play with it.
webuser.bus.umich.edu/Organizations/FinanceClub/resources/BootstrappingMath.xls